# why does my flask backend keep closing the connection to my flutter app

Tags: python, flutter, http, flask, pdf

iam currently working on a Flutter app with Flask backend. I only have the problem when I want to download my PDF file via http request, I almost always get the following error: Unhandled Exception: ClientException: Connection closed while receiving data. But only almost always. I've always used Postman to test the API, strangely it always works there.Sometimes it also works strangely. the backend is on a cloud server, so not in my network.

The Flask Code(removed the other unrelevant functions):

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request,send_file,Response
import sqlite3
import json
import base64
import time
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
from os.path import exists
from werkzeug.serving import WSGIRequestHandler

WSGIRequestHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.post('/auth1/app_frontend/get_res/brochures/<ID>.pdf')
def get_brochure(ID):
    auth=request.headers.get("X-Session-Token")
    if checkValidSession(auth,durationPeriod):
        if exists("data/brochures/"+ID+".pdf"):
            return send_file("data/brochures/"+ID+".pdf", mimetype="application/pdf")
        else:
            return jsonify({"response": [{"Type":"request-brochure-success"}, {"Payload":"null"}]}) 
    else:
        return jsonify({"response": [{"Type":"Auth-Error"}, {"Payload":"null"}]}) 



WSGIRequestHandler.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

The Flutter Future(removed the domain):

```
Future<Uint8List> getBytes() async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://FQDN:5000/auth1/app_frontend/get_res/brochures/3.pdf"),
      headers: {
        "Connection": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Encoding": "keep-alive",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "X-Session-Token": widget.sessionId,
      },);
    return response.bodyBytes;
  }
```

The Flutter FutureBuilder

```
Container(child: FutureBuilder(future: getBytes(), builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if(snapshot.hasData){
          return PDFView(pdfData: snapshot.data, enableSwipe: true,swipeHorizontal: true,);
        }else if(snapshot.hasError){
          return CircularProgressIndicator(color: Colors.red,);
        }else{
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      })),
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel main, 3.13.0-9.0.pre.37, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965], locale de-DE)
    • Flutter version 3.13.0-9.0.pre.37 on channel main at C:\dev\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 8a01c9b707 (4 hours ago), 2023-07-24 12:59:06 -0700
    • Engine revision 2b8d83fa20
    • Dart version 3.1.0 (build 3.1.0-333.0.dev)
    • DevTools version 2.25.0

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Highling\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.5)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.6.33829.357
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] VS Code (version 1.80.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Highling\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.68.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 14 (API 34) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 115.0.5790.102
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 115.0.1901.183

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```